# Unity 5 webplayer forces development build

Tags: build, unity-game-engine

how do you publish to webplayer without Unity publishing a development build? I tried to publish streamed, offline, development.. and, of course, with nothing selected. Unity only builds webplayer development builds.

I'm using the most recent version of Unity 5. I do have some errors after exiting one of the levels, cuz I didn't cleanly tell the Enemies what to do after the Player is dead, or something like if.. the player exists go kill her. I just exit the level and the game plays just fine. But can this be the reason? Unity thinking that I still have errors to fix and therefore I can't publish a normal build? I can publish OK to PC though..

Thanks!

EDIT:

Oh, nevermind, I managed to find some answers. The Webplayer installed with Unity goes automatically in Dev mode. It doesn't have any right click options to disable dev build. So I had to reinstall the player via their website. But if other people have their Webplayers set to Dev Build they will see this game with all its errors. : / No biggie, since this is just a learning project, but still.. I would very much like to have a clean build if I'm showing it to anyone else.